# Reliable source of cities time zones that track changes in daylight savings time

Tags: time, timezone

Is there a reliable source for cities timezones, that keep track of changes in daylight saving times?

For example, after the 2010 Chilean earthquake, the DST was postponed (a political decision). Not even [Google was able to keep the right time in Chile](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/F2Sh3RENnoE) breaking, among other things, [Google Authenticator](https://code.google.com/p/google-authenticator/issues/detail?id=149).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the primary source of this type of data is the [IANA Time Zone Database](http://www.iana.org/time-zones), also known as the "Olson" database, tz database, tzdb, or zoneinfo.

While this source is not an authority in a standards-body sense, it acts as the defacto origin of most other time zone data in just about every system, language, and library.  The only outlier is Microsoft, and even they are moving towards it in newer frameworks like WinRT.

You can read more in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info), and [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database).

With regard to the example you gave, this is reflected properly in the tzdb.  You can review [Chile's current entry, in the unofficial sources on GitHub](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/2015a/southamerica#L1099-L1277).  They include comments regarding the 2010 earthquake that you mentioned.  (Likely, Google had simply not updated to the current release quickly enough.)